# How to write a reproducible as_chunk command in flextable R

Tags: r, flextable, officer, reproducible-research

While in the process to create a flextable in R, I'am unable to write a reproducible quote for a section.

This table will be updated every month, therefore adding a new column. To make this reproducible most of my code is in the form on column numbers.

I'm trying to add the image of red_upward and green_downward arrows based on the logic of increase or decrease from the previous month.

The table looks like so:

[image]

To be able to achieve this I used the `as_paragraph` command within compose. And within `as_paragraph` I put together the value from the column followed by the image of the arrow.
The problem is in picking the value of the column. I cannot make the column selection reproducible.

```
flextable(tab3_data) %>%
  theme_zebra(odd_header = "transparent", even_header = "transparent") %>%
  theme_box() %>%
  align(align = "center", part = "header") %>%
  width(j = c(2:(ncol(tab3_data) - 6)), width = 1.2, unit = "cm") %>% # col. no. deciding the width
  width(j = c((ncol(tab3_data) - 7 + 1):(ncol(tab3_data))), width = 1.9, unit = "cm") %>%
  width(j = ~`Disease Description`, width = 4.6, unit = "cm") %>%
  vline(j = c(1, ((ncol(tab3_data) - 6)), (ncol(tab3_data) - 4), (ncol(tab3_data) - 2)), border = fp_border(color = "black", width = 1.5)) %>% # col. no. deciding the location of thinker vertical lines
  border_outer(border = fp_border(color = "black", width = 1.5)) %>%
  paginate(init = FALSE, hdr_ftr = TRUE) %>%
  compose(
    i = tab3_data[(ncol(tab3_data) - 6)] > tab3_data[(ncol(tab3_data) - 6 - 1)], # col. no. for logic
    j = colnames(tab3_data[(ncol(tab3_data) - 6)]), # col. no. for applying the logic to
    value = as_paragraph(
      as_chunk(
        sprintf("%.0f", `2023_Mar`), # here column number and name are both not working
        fp_text_default(color = "black")
      ), " ",
      as_image(src = red_arrow, width = 0.15, height = 0.25)
    )
  ) %>%
  compose(
    i = tab3_data[(ncol(tab3_data) - 6)] < tab3_data[(ncol(tab3_data) - 6 - 1)],
    j = colnames(tab3_data[(ncol(tab3_data) - 6)]),
    value = as_paragraph(
      as_chunk(
        sprintf("%.0f", `2023_Mar`), # here column number and name are both not working
        fp_text_default(color = "black")
      ), " ",
      as_image(src = green_arrow, width = 0.15, height = 0.25)
    )
  )
```

`2023_Mar` is going to change to `2023_Apr` and so on....

The options I have tried:

1. Col. no.--> `tab3_data[(ncol(tab3_data)-6)]`

> Error - Error in sprintf("%.1f", tab3_data[(ncol(tab3_data) - 6)]) :
> 'list' object cannot be coerced to type 'double'

2. Using the col name -->  `colnames(tab3_data[ncol(tab3_data)-6])`

> Error in sprintf("%.1f", colnames(tab3_data[ncol(tab3_data) - 2])) :
> invalid format '%.1f'; use format %s for character objects

so I changed the format to %s. but then it prints the column name and not the value in that cell.

**I'm expecting the output as in the image, but by using reproducible code and not hard coding the column name.**

Comment: can you share the data please?

Comment: Without data it is hard to be sure but you can try using the column index instead of the name with `j = ncol_keys(.) - 6`. Or the error comes from `colnames(tab3_data[ncol(tab3_data)-6])` which should be `colnames(tab3_data)[ncol(tab3_data)-6]`. Again, without data it is hard to tell